# Unit-testing Jersey with Mocks

Tags: rest, jersey, mockito

We have a test which extends JerseyTest and we need a mock service injected into it. How can we do this?

Thanks

Comment: Jersey's a new one on me.  I thought everyone used either JUnit or TestNG.

Comment: Extending JerseyTest allows you to add regular JUnit @Test annotations, but I don't know how to inject a Mock service in the Spring configuration used by jersey-spring. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you really need to inject mockito when it only has static methods?

Comment: I needed to inject Mockito mock objects, not Mockito class. After a long trial and error process I finally solved this by injecting MockableContext as explained here http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jersey.user/8431 and using GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory. Don't hesitate to grant points if this helped you :)

Comment: If you solved your question, please respond to it yourself with the answer, and mark the answer as accepted. This way the system will be able to see the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Edit : **this solution only works with Jersey 1.x**, and is therefore quite outdated.

It refers to http://geek.riffpie.com/unit-testing-restful-jersey-services-glued-together-with-spring/ library.

If you use Spring, you can extend AbstractSpringAwareJerseyTest instead of JerseyTest, and inject whatever you need.

As requested, a little snippet of code :

```
public class MyClassTest extends AbstractSpringAwareJerseyTest{

  @Autowired
  private LdapSetupAndTearDown ldapSetupAndTearDown;

  @Before
  public void setUp2() throws Exception {
    ldapSetupAndTearDown.setUp();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown2() throws Exception {
    ldapSetupAndTearDown.tearDown();
  }

  public MyClassTest () throws Exception {
    super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder()
    .contextPath("JSONUserServiceTest")
    .contextParam("contextConfigLocation",
        "classpath:/ctx-config-test.xml,classpath:/ctx-core.xml, classpath:/ctx-jmx-test.xml, classpath:ctx-jersey.xml, classpath:ctx-ldap.xml, classpath:ctx-ldap-test.xml")
    .servletClass(SpringServlet.class).contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class).build());
  }
```

Comment: I guess he points to: http://geek.riffpie.com/unit-testing-restful-jersey-services-glued-together-with-spring/ I didn't get it working, though.

Comment: Exactly, this tutorial led me to this solution, and it works fine. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate how `@Autowired` beans get injected into test class (did you annotate some `@RunWith`, for example)? Could you pass a simple example of your test class here?

Comment: That's it? I tried exactly that but it didn't work. Well, guess I did something wrong then. Have to check it...

Comment: Do you use maven ? (I mention that to be sure the path to the conf files are correct) Did you add <context:annotation-config /> in your conf ?

Comment: You might also need to have <context:component-scan base-package="..." /> for your REST classes to ber scanned

Comment: Yeah I had everything in place and Spring was initialized successfully in the container. Everything worked, except `@Autowiring` Spring beans into the test class (they were always just null).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23362/discussion-between-samuel-eustachi-and-tuukka-mustonen)

Comment: I can't find any class called "AbstractSpringAwareJerseyTest".  What package is this located in?

Comment: As pointed out by Tuuka, I refered to : http://geek.riffpie.com/unit-testing-restful-jersey-services-glued-together-with-spring/
But this only applies to Jersey 1.x, not to Jersey 2, so I am afraid this is quite outdated. I didn't find any good solution for Jersey 2 yet.